# Push notifications emulate 100000 subscribers

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have made a service which sends push notifications to subscribers via GCM and APNS. For a small number of subscribers everything works fine, but I`d like to test it, say, for 100000 subscribers. In particular, I am interested how service workers act when trying to fetch a data for such amount of subscribers, what if my DB or server is not able to serve all of them in one second etc.

For now I don`t have such amount of subscribers, are there any way to emulate them for testing purposes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Service Worker](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-worker/) is a client-side JavaScript Worker, so the number of subscribers should be irrelevant. However, do note that when sending downstream messages, you can only have up to [1000 registration tokens](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) at a time, so you'll have to repeat the batch by 100 (in this example). Once a message is sent to GCM, the subscribers' web client should be able to handle it separately.

You have to have valid `registration_ids` to test it out to that degree. That means, registering thousands of clients! It can still be done, though. There are a few ready-made scripts or sites where you can test GCM, but you'll still need to provide those registration_ids.

Comment: Thank you for a reply. Can you provide a link to such scripts which you mention in your answer? I would like to try them out